# Ember Form Action returns Undefined Input Value

Tags: ember.js

I'm running into a weird issue with Ember.js.

I built out a basic search form like so, with an Ember input field that submits to a form action 'submitSearch':

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
 actions: {
   submitSearch: function() {
      var searchItem = this.get('searchItem');
       this.transitionTo({queryParams: {'q':searchItem}});
   }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <form {{action "submitSearch" on="submit"}}>
   <fieldset>
    {{input type="text" class="form-control" value=searchItem}}
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-search" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" />
   </fieldset>  
  </form>
 </div>
```

Any reason why I would be getting a value of 'undefined' when logging out searchItem?  I've tried just about everything including creating a model, but I can't get the input to save.

Answer (score 1):

The `searchTerm` value in your template is referring to your controller's `searchTerm` property, not a property of your route (by default when referring to a property in your template, it is referring to a property of the corresponding controller).

To get the value in the route, simply do `this.get('controller.searchTerm')`.